# To retrive the sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select case  
      when SUBSTRING (ltrim([ producet_name]),1,1)= 'a'   then 
    'Grade A'
    else
      ''
    end Grade from product
```

here the query prints he grade A where the starting letter of the value starts with a/ in the same way I want the query to print all letters with respective grades using concat or any other method

Comment: Your statement doesn't really make sense. Please post some sample and expected data at least, please.

Comment: I want to print the grades of each column values if the string contains a-z letters. if the string starts with the letter 'A' then it prints grade A, if it contains b it prints grade B

Comment: What does the data within `[producet_name]` look like? You haven't posted any Sample data still. We can't access your data, so we don't know. Also, `[ producet_name]` is an awful name for a column. Don't include whitespace in an object's name (especially as a prefix!), and product doesn't contain the letter `e`. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you appears to want :

```
select *, (case left(ltrim(product_name), 1) 
                when 'a' then 'Grade A'
                when 'b' then 'Grade B'
                else ''
           end) as Grade
from product p;
```

You can also simplfy this as via `concat()`:

```
select concat('Grade ', left(ltrim(product_name), 1)) as Garde
from product p;
```

Comment: How can you possibly know this when the question is so vague?

Comment: yes that was the correct answer but i want in one shot than using when condition multiple time

Comment: @kavya. . . Second version should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work for your question

```
select 'Grade' + ' ' +upper(SUBSTRING (ltrim([ producet_name]),1,1)) AS  Grade from product
```

this will give you results as

```
Grade A
Grade B 
Grade C
...
```